# How to declare UML class diagram scanner scan declaration?

Tags: java, c#, class, uml, diagram

Hi what is the proper way to declare a scanner on a uml class diagram, like this
+scan: Scanner  or +scan: Scanner(System.in) or something else. Also anything else I should add? Oh yeah I'm representing java.

Thanks

Comment: I would try this : +scan: Scanner(System.in)

Comment: @HarryCoder you are wrong, `+scan: Scanner(System.in)` does not follow UML notation

Comment: @bruno _<prop-type> is the name of the Classifier that is the type of the Property._ but UML does not specify the chars you can use in _<prop_type>._ So you could see  `Scanner(System.in)`  as the type. Strange, but not wrong.

Comment: @qwerty_so clearly because OP says `I'm representing java` the form `Scanner(System.in)` is the initialization and that one must be placed after '='

Comment: @bruno That might be. I can read Java and write a helloWorld, but that's it. Then here's it's a context-thing.

Answer (score 4):

If I well understand *scan* is an attribute of a class and `Scanner(System.in)` the way you initialize it (default value)

As specified in the [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1)  §9.5.4 from page 113 the notation is :

```
[<visibility>] [‘/’] <name> [‘:’ <prop-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’]
    [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘ <prop-modifier > [‘,’ <prop-modifier >]* ’}’]
```

A first remark concern the visibility, '+' means *public*, are you sure you want your attribute public ? This is dangerous because that means it can be modified from any other class.

Out of that if you want to only indicate its visibility and type : `+scan : Scanner`

If you want to also indicate its default value : `+scan : Scanner = Scanner(System.in)`

So `+scan: Scanner(System.in)` is wrong